# Countdown js, keeps restarting

Tags: javascript

I'm learing so please be kind :-)

I found the perfect countdown clock.
What I want to achieve is that after `1` the words `Lift Off!` come, but for some reason the countdown clock keeps showing `1`

```
var startNum;
var currentNum;

function addClassDelayed(jqObj, c, to) {    
    setTimeout(function() { jqObj.addClass(c); }, to);
}

function anim() { 
  addClassDelayed($("#countdown"), "puffer", 600);
  if (currentNum == 0)  $('#countdown').html("Lift Off!"); else currentNum--;
  $('#countdown').html(currentNum+1);
  $('#countdown').removeClass("puffer");
}

$(function() {
  startNum = 5; 
  currentNum = startNum;
  $("#countdown").html(currentNum); // init first time based on n
  self.setInterval(function(){anim()},1325);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#countdown').html(currentNum+1);` overwrites anything you would have set previously.

```
function anim() { 
  addClassDelayed($("#countdown"), "puffer", 600);
  if (currentNum == 0) {
      $('#countdown').html("Lift Off!");
      clearInterval(token)
  } else {
      currentNum--;
      $('#countdown').html(currentNum+1); // Only show if not "Lift Off!"
  }
  $('#countdown').removeClass("puffer");
}

var token;
$(function() {
  startNum = 5; 
  currentNum = startNum;
  $("#countdown").html(currentNum); // init first time based on n
  token = self.setInterval(function(){anim()},1325);
});
```

Added `clearInverval` per Tyler's suggestion

Comment: The `anim` function will still run every 1.3 seconds for the rest of the page's life. Probably a good idea to clear out the interval after it's complete too.

Comment: @Wouter I added the clearInterval. Should work fine but note that I didn't test it...

Comment: @Clint, I saw it, but how do I make the Lift off stay a little bit longer, maybe 2 sec longer.

Comment: @Wouter Is there some code missing from the question? I don't see anything that would remove "Lift Off!" from the page after the interval is cleared.

Comment: @Clint Oh yes, you can't see my css behing it.....#countdown.puffer {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(.6,.6);
  transition: all .4s ease-in;
} So with the "Lift Off" it needs to stay

Comment: @Wouter Try moving the `addCssDelayed` line to the `else` block of `anim`. It may take some tinkering to get the animations exactly how you want.

Comment: @Clint I've tried the put removeClass("puffer) just before the "Lift Off!" line but that didn't work. As basically the puffer class needs to be removed when "Lift Off! is showing

Comment: @Clint you were spot on!! All I had to do was putting the addCssDelayed in the else block!! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let's look in your anim function:

```
function anim() { 
  addClassDelayed($("#countdown"), "puffer", 600);
  if (currentNum == 0)  $('#countdown').html("Lift Off!"); else currentNum--;
  $('#countdown').html(currentNum+1);
  $('#countdown').removeClass("puffer");
}
```

If braces are missing after an if-statement, they're implied to only apply to the following statement (singular). Based on that, let's add braces around the parts of the code where they're implied to be:

```
function anim() { 
  addClassDelayed($("#countdown"), "puffer", 600);
  if (currentNum == 0) {
    $('#countdown').html("Lift Off!");
  } else {
    currentNum--;
  }
  $('#countdown').html(currentNum+1);
  $('#countdown').removeClass("puffer");
}
```

Based on that, when the currentNum is 0, the contents of `#countdown` become "Lift Off!" then *immediately* change to `currentNum + 1`. That's why it's never finishing off by showing "Lift Off!"

This code will either print "Lift Off!" or the current number (which then gets decremented after getting referenced):

```
var startNum;
var currentNum;
var countdownInterval;

function addClassDelayed(jqObj, c, to) {    
    setTimeout(function() { jqObj.addClass(c); }, to);
}

function anim() { 
  addClassDelayed($("#countdown"), "puffer", 600);
  if (currentNum === 0) {
    $('#countdown').html('Lift Off!');
    clearInterval(countdownInterval);
  } else {
    $('#countdown').html(currentNum--);
  }
  $('#countdown').removeClass("puffer");
}

$(function() {
  startNum = 5; 
  currentNum = startNum;
  $("#countdown").html(currentNum); // init first time based on n
  countdownInterval = self.setInterval(function(){anim()},1325);
});
```

Comment: I'd mentioned this on a separate answer, but might I suggest clearing the interval after it's complete. No use calling a function every second for the rest of the page's life cycle if it will never do anything again.

Comment: I've picked this as an answer as it explains my mistake in detail. Thax Chris. One more question, where do I put my interval clearing? After Lift Off?

Comment: Yeah, @TylerRoper, I saw that comment and thought "hm, that's a good idea".

Comment: @Wouter You'd clear the interval along with the Lift Off bit; I've updated my answer to include what that'd look like

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your code. You overwrite `Lift off!` after the `if` `else` statements.

```
function anim() { 
  addClassDelayed($("#countdown"), "puffer", 600);

  // Add a return statement here.
  if (currentNum == 0) {
      $('#countdown').html("Lift Off!");
      return;
  }

  else {
     currentNum--;
  }
  $('#countdown').html(currentNum+1);
  $('#countdown').removeClass("puffer");
}
```